# Defined class gives undefined class error

Tags: java

I'm getting an undefined method for the methods showTotal  problem even though the method is defined.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 String command ;
 Machine M = null;
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter your command");
        command = sc.next();
        String[] commands = command.split(" ");
        if (commands[0] == "create" )
        {
           M = new Machine (commands[1],commands[2]);
        }

        else if (commands[0] == "total" )
        {
            M.showTotal();
        }



    }
}
}
```

Comment: Off topic but you resolve `command` to `sc.next()`, (While will only be one complete token) and then you call `split()` on it. Also you have an infinite loop

Comment: Also could you show the code for the `Machine` class?

Comment: I'm not sure I got your point , can you please explain it ?

Comment: Happens when you call total before create? Also, machine class code would help

Comment: i didn't know how to copy it here ( engine kept telling me it had too much code ) so here it is https://jsfiddle.net/h5ve09wp/

Comment: @MohamedKoubàa [edit]

Comment: Actually , it's a compilation error not a runtime one

Answer (score 0):

You need to call nextLine() instead of next() for your scanner.

```
    command = sc.next();
    String[] commands = command.split(" ");
```

You won't be able to split the string command because it can never have a space in it because you are using next(). Change it so you are grabbing the entire line like so

```
    command = sc.nextLine(); //grab the line
    String[] commands = command.split(" ");
```

Then your if statments need to use the equals() method for strings, == will not compare strings in java the way you want it to. You also need to ensure your array returned by split has a length >= 3 to prevent index out of bounds and check that M is not null when calling showTotal()

```
    if (commands[0].equals("create") && comands.length() >= 3)
    {
       M = new Machine (commands[1],commands[2]);
    }

    else if (commands[0].equals("total") && M != null)
    {
        M.showTotal();
    }
```